# How to match filetype with regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm stuck trying to get a regex to match a filetype in a sorting script.

```
Dir.foreach(savedirs[0]) do |x|
  puts "Matching " + x + " against filetypes."
  case x
  when x.match(/^.*\.exe$/i) then puts x
  when x.match(/\.jpe?g$/) then FileUtils.move(x, sortpath[".exe"], :verbose => true)
  when x =~ /\.jpg$/ then FileUtils.move(x, sortpath[".jpg"])
  end
end
```

I can't get any of these to match on in windows. All I need is to confirm that a given filename matches against compatible filetypes.

Comment: You’re rather looking for the file name extension than the file type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get the extension like this instead:

```
ext = File.extname(filename)

case ext
when ".exe" then ...
when ".jpg", ".jpeg" then ...
...
end
```

I like to keep regex out of it...